# Regular expression to escape double quotes within double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a string that needs to be parsed as JSON.

The problem is, it may sometimes contain double quotes, causing errors in parsing.

For example:

```
{
    "id_clients":"58844",

    "id_clients_name" : ""100" test"qw"
}
```

I need a regex to replace any double quotes between the opening and closing `"` with a `\"`.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to fix the problem at whatever is generating the JSON.

Comment: How do you know where is **opening and closing `"`**

Comment: First and last before/after the ':'.

Comment: I concur with @ExplosionPills, you need to use code that already knows how to build JSON if you can...those quotes should be escaped BEFORE you get the JSON string...otherwise, you're going to need some complex look-ahead/look-behind expressions that will likely get nasty.  I'm better than most people with regexes (not an expert by any means) and I wouldn't want to figure this out.

Comment: e.g. what if your JSON does: "id_clients":""588","44"", how does it know to ignore the ", after 588 because it looks like JSON.

Comment: Alright, fixing the generator it is, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried it just for fun, even though it is certainly better to fix the generator. This might work in your case, or at least inspire you:

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ms4wq/3/)

```
$( function() 
{
  var myString = "{ \"na\"\"me\": \"va\"lue\", \"tes\"\"t\":\"ok\" }";
  var myRegexp = /\s*\"([\w\"]+)\"\s*[,}:]/g;
  var match;
  var matches = [];

  // Save all the matches
  while((match = myRegexp.exec(myString)) !== null)
  {
      matches.push(match[1]);
      console.log(match[1]);
  }

  // Process them
  var newString = myString;
  for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++)
  {
      var newVal = matches[i].replace(/\"/g, '\\\"'); 
      newString = newString.replace(matches[i], newVal);
  }
  alert(myString + "\n" + newString);
}
);
```

Comment: I'm marking this one as accepted. I've already sorted my issue out, but maybe someone else will find this solution helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try, although this will work only for the opening tags :

```
.replace(/\"\"/g, '\\""');
```

Comment: Yeah, I already have something like that. Namely: replace(/\"\"([0-9A-Za-z _-]+)\"/g, '\"\\"\$1\\"'). The problem is with the quotes in the middle of the string.