# Escape double quotes within double quotes

Tags: java, regex, json

I have a string `[{"Id":"1","msg":""Lorem Ipsum""}]` in which I need to just escape the quotes inside the quotes like this `[{"Id":"1","msg":"\"Lorem Ipsum\""}]`. I don't have access to generator code to modify, so I'm looking for a regex solution or efficient Java solution.

I tried selecting matches with  `\"[^\"]*?(\"*)[^\"]*?\"` which is of no use. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note that it isn't guaranteed that the pattern is always two double quotes together, it can be something like this too `"Lorem "Ipsum" test"`, which should become `"Lorem \"Ipsum\" test"`.

PS: I've already looked at [Regular expression to escape double quotes within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568011/regular-expression-to-escape-double-quotes-within-double-quotes)

Comment: What happened when you ported the solution in your linked question to Java?

Comment: It didn't escape as I've shown above. It just returned the initial string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

**A finite automaton - the theoretical equivalent of a regex - can't parse recursive structures**. Since you can have inner quotes, and possible inner-inner quotes, your problem can't be solved using a regex.

Although modern regex engines can overcome this problem with several extensions, don't waste your time on hunting quotes-within-quotes. You'll soon find out that you're actually building a full blown JSON parser.

As [@johnchen902 stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213815/51197), even a turing-machine powered parser can not handle ambiguities - so you better not try to suggest a fix to the broken JSON.

### Solutions

#### Create the JSON using a dedicated utility

The given string [is not a valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/). It's probably created using string concatenation, which is generally a bad idea because it does not escape correctly. You should use a JSON library that can build JSON from a Java data structure, like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Create a list of Objects, add an Object-to-Object dictionary to it, and let the library do the escaping and conversions.

#### Ask the creator to use a validator

If you have received the String from an external source, it's perfectly legitimate to ask for a *valid* json you can work with. I guess that the creator stitched Strings together, which is the wrong way to build a structured language. Ask the original creator to use a standard library for creating JSONs, or at least use a validator. All modern programming languages offer these mechanisms.

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to escape this programmatically.

Comment: It even can't be parsed by parser because a string may have several meanings. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @johnchen902 Correct, but at least it can be validated and pick one of any number of possible interpretation. The point is that it is useless - the OP should either create or receive a valid JSON, not mess with fixing broken strings.

Comment: Nice solution@AdamMatan

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, because a string may have several meanings.

For example:

```
[{"Id":"1","msg":""Lorem Ipsum""}]
```

May means

```
[{"Id":"1","msg":""Lorem Ipsum""}]
```

That is, it can be escaped (parsed) as

```
[{"Id":"1\",\"msg\":\"\"Lorem Ipsum\""}]
```

There's no way for a program to determine its meaning unless more rules are given.

Answer (score 0):

```
String escaped = str.replaceAll(":\"\"(.+?)\"\"([,}])", ":\"\\\\\"$1\\\\\"\"$2");
```