# wp_insert_post() altering double quotes

Tags: jquery, wordpress, upload

I'm trying to upload a script to Wordpress using wp_insert_post() but once it gets to the server the quotes are changed in just a couple of places to `&#8221;` which probably explains why I can't seem to get it working. I've tried using the sanitize() function but this messes everything up by inserting `</p>` tags at the end of all lines so that's not really an option.

I read here [Escape double quotes within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213468/escape-double-quotes-within-double-quotes) that concatenated strings (which I am using, as well as heredoc strings) could be the cause of the problem, but I am unsure of how exactly to solve the problem. All suggestions welcome - unfortunately the jQuery script I am attempting to upload is a gallery built from images uploaded by users to Wordpress via WP-Contact7/Flamingo.

Or would simply escaping all quotes work? But what about strings that simply have to be concatenated? Like `<img src="' . $someImgUrl . '...';`?

Here's one of the four similarly-constructed strings I'm attemptning to upload...

```
                        $gallBd2A = <<< gallBd2A
                                </div><!-- id="rundgang"-->

                                    <div id="gallKnopfeTeil">
                                        <input type="button" id="bildZuKnopf" name="1" class="gallKnopfe" value=" >>> " onClick="bildZu(this)">
                                        <input type="button" id="bildAbKnopf" name="1" class="gallKnopfe" value=" <<< " onClick="bildAb(this)">
                                    </div><!-- id="gallKnopfeTeil" -->

                                <script src='./jquery.js'>
                                </script>


                                <script>
                                    function probeZufug(bd){
                                        var e = document.getElementById('probeKaste');
                                        e.innerHTML += "<br/>" + bd;
                                    }
                                </script>


                                <script>
                                        //  if (plusZiff == 7)
                                        //  jzZiff < 6? jzZiff++: jzZiff=1;
                                        //  if (minderZiff == 0) { minderZiff = 6;}
                                        //  jzZiff > 1? jzZiff--: jzZiff=6;

                                            // jQuery('#bild1').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild2').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild3').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild4').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild5').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild6').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild7').fadeOut(100);
                                            jQuery('#bild8').fadeOut(100);

                                        function bildZu(ds){
                                            var jzZiff = parseInt(ds.name);
                                            var plusZiff = jzZiff+1;

gallBd2A;
```

Then after four such strings, I concatenate them with:

```
$gzGallBd = $gallKaskBd . $gallBd1 . $gallBdM . $gallBd2A . $gallBd2B . $gallBd2C . $gallBd2D . $gallBd2L;
```

This string is then added to a post-object whose object variables are passed to wp_insert_post() as parameters of the post-array.

The script works perfectly well when outputted on the page used to upload it (as a check) and the uploaded code works if I copy and paste it back to a local page not inside wordpress.

But in the wordpress post I get the pictures side by side as if no jQuery script has hidden them. Until I investigate the post and click to save it in visual mode, at which point the images are stacked as intended, but without any button functionality, since the onClick(..) function has disappeared from the `<input type="button"...>` elements.

If necessary I will post the full code shortly, any feedback int he meantime will be very, very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using following method to insert post :

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $someImgUrl = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/26/13/09/organic-1280537_960_720.jpg";
    $new_post = array(
          'ID' => '',
          'post_author' => $user_id, 
          'post_category' => '',
          'post_content' => '', 
          'post_title' => 'custom post',
          'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $post_id =  wp_insert_post( $new_post );

I am getting double quotes in my post content using this method. Please elaborate your question if not getting worked.

Comment: Yes, I am using wp_insert_post() and everything else is uploading OK - post_title, post_status, the rest of the content, etc...only this animation is proving tricky. No idea why it's only converting certain double quotes???

Comment: Ok i see.. you are having problem in jquery srcipt i.e. OnClick function is not working. Share your script or complete code so i can test it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, in the end I altered the code to use only one single-quoted string with single quotes within it escaped. I also was having a problem with >>> which were apparently closing some tags inside wordpress *or something*. See the answer for further clarification.

Comment: Yes thanks, at long last! Guess you just have to do things the right way sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since my original question has gone unanswered, I'll put up the solution for anyone with the same problem:

I rewrote the original script above, putting everything in single-quoted strings with escapes for any single quotes and dispensing with the heredocs, as the closing heredoc tag needs to be at the very start of a newline, which may or may not be a problem as the string is passed around.

The full jquery/javascript functionality was put in its own .js file in wordpress's file structure and included with

```
function eigenSchrifte() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'schleicher1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/schleicher1.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.12.4', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'eigenSchrifte' );
```

The .css specific to the gallery I ended up putting in the theme's single.php page since the slider will only be shown on individual posts.

That left the dynamically-generated html with the `<img src="...">` tags, and the php script to build the gallery now contains nothing but html, which uploads perfectly well, albeit without `>>>` or even `&gt;&gt;&gt;` as the button text.

A rough approximation of the final html-construction runs like so (not so enlightening in itself, but useful for comparison with the original attempt):

```
$galleryString1 = '<div id="carousel">';

$dynamicGalleryString = '';


foreach ($imageArray as $targetImage) {
        $targetImage++;
        $dynamicGalleryString .= find_and_copy_target_uploaded_image_returns_full_image_tag($targetImage, $newFolder);

} //


$galleryString2 =                               
        '</div><!-- id="carousel"-->

            <div id="galleryButtonDiv">
                <input type="button" id="nxPicButton" name="1" class="galleryButton" value=" ++ " onClick="nextPic(this)">
                <input type="button" id="prevPicButton" name="1" class="galleryButton" value=" -- " onClick="prevPic(this)">
            </div><!-- id="galleryButtonDiv" -->
        ';
```