# Regex replace - Double quotes in json

Tags: json, regex

I have json string and it is coming as

```
{“test”:”this is “test” of test”,”result”:”your result is “out” in our website”}
```

I need make it valid json by regex_replace as you can see above is not valid json. 
Expected result after replacement:

{“test”:”this is ‘test’ of test”,”result”:”your result is ‘out’ in our website”}

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a way to escape the quotes before sending at as json? That would be a much better solution.

Comment: No, this invalid json is coming in column. I have to extract required info but facing invalid json issues

Comment: Are there strings with multiple double quoted words within the value, like `“test”:”this is “test” "of" test”`? Are there strings with spaces or any other non word characters within the double quoted passages, like `“test”:”this is “test of" test”`? Are there strings with no double quote issue at all? Does it actually happen, that the key is the same as a quoted word within the value, just like your `"test"`?

Comment: 1) No , 2) No , 3) Yes , 4) Yes

Answer (score 4):

You can probably just match all strings no matter what the content
as long as it is surrounded by a proper JSON structure.
Then replace double quotes accordingly from within a  sub *Callback Function*.

The regex to match a pseudo-valid JSON string is this

`r'([:\[,{]\s*)"(.*?)"(?=\s*[:,\]}])'`

see https://regex101.com/r/KgCz1L/1

Within the callback just replaces all double quotes with a single quote `'`

Python sample:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = '''
... {"test":"this is "test" of test","result":"your result is "out" in our website"}
... '''
>>>
>>> def repl_call(m):
...     preq = m.group(1)
...     qbody = m.group(2)
...     qbody = re.sub( r'"', "'", qbody )
...     return preq + '"' + qbody + '"'
...
>>> print( re.sub( r'([:\[,{]\s*)"(.*?)"(?=\s*[:,\]}])', repl_call, text ))

{"test":"this is 'test' of test","result":"your result is 'out' in our website"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this. I was inspired by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576246/9487478 and modified the regex and the replacement just a little so it's working for your usecase.

```js
var myString = '{"test":"this is "test" "of" test","result":"your result "is-out" in our website"}';
var myRegexp = /\"(.+?)\"\s*[,}:\n]/g;
var match;
var matches = [];

// Save all the matches
while ((match = myRegexp.exec(myString)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}

// Process them
var newString = myString;
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  var newVal = matches[i].replace(/\"/g, "'");
  newString = newString.replace(matches[i], newVal);
}
console.log(newString);
```